# Change learning rate within minibatch - keras

Tags: keras, imbalanced-data

I have a problem with imbalanced labels, for example 90% of the data have the label 0 and the rest 10% have the label 1.

I want to teach the network with minibatches. So I want the optimizer to give the examples labeled with 1 a learning rate (or somehow change the gradients to be) greater by 9 than those with label 0.

is there any way of doing that?

The problem is that the whole training process is done in this line:

`history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=minibatch_size, validation_data=(valX, valY), verbose=0)`

is there a way to change the fit method in the low level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the class_weight parameter of keras.

From keras doc:

class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only).

Example of using it in imbalance data:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data#class_weights

```
class_weights={"class_1": 1, "class_2": 10}
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=minibatch_size, validation_data=(valX, valY), verbose=0, class_weight=class_weights)
```

Full example:

```
# Examine the class label imbalance
# you can use your_df['label_class_column'] or just the trainY values.
neg, pos = np.bincount(your_df['label_class_column'])
total = neg + pos
print('Examples:\n    Total: {}\n    Positive: {} ({:.2f}% of total)\n'.format(
    total, pos, 100 * pos / total))

# Scaling by total/2 helps keep the loss to a similar magnitude.
# The sum of the weights of all examples stays the same.
weight_for_0 = (1 / neg)*(total)/2.0 
weight_for_1 = (1 / pos)*(total)/2.0

class_weight = {0: weight_for_0, 1: weight_for_1}
```

Comment: Thanks Niv, 
I still have some problem with this because the network i'm trying to teach has only one output and the different classes are binary. I've tried to add this as is but it didn't work.

Comment: Its works fine in binary situations.
I have added a full example.